# Customize change detection to perform deep object compare instead of reference equals check in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I've created a filter-pipe to perform filtering for an array of objects.
This pipe gets a `filterArgs` object which contains some properties on which basis the items should be filtered.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Item[], filterArgs: any): Item[] {
        return items.filter(item => ...);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have some input fields where users can set the filter arguments. I bind the properties of the `filterArgs` object directly and apply the filter for the items like this:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="filterArgs.dateFrom">
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="filterArgs.dateTo">

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | filter:filterArgs>...</li>
</ul>
```

In my component, the `filterArgs` object is defined as follows (schematic):

```
public filterArgs: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.filterArgs = {
        dateFrom = undefined,
        dateTo = undefined
    };
}
```

So the problem now is, that the filter doesn't get applied when one of the input fields change. As far is I've understood Angular's change detection, this is because the `filterArgs` object's reference doesn't change and therefore Angular doesn't detect any changes. This is expected behavior and by design.

My question now is: What's the proposed way to resolve this issue?

The naive approach would be to create a new `filterArgs` object every time an input field changes, so that the reference of this object gets updated. In that case Angular's change detection would kick in. But there must be a better way to do this. I'd image that I could annotate the `filterArgs` property with some kind of attribute that tells Angular to perform a "deep object compare" for detecting changes.

Answer (score 2):

For components and directives you can implement `DoCheck` to perform custom change detection but for pipes this is not supported.

Alternatively you can "optimize" the pipe by using

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
```

And return cached result when the filter didn't change

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An impure pipe is not an option for me due to performance reasons. I also don't need change detection for the filtered items themselfs. The custom change detection is only needed for the `filterArgs` object. I think I'll go with an immutable `filterArgs` object like stated [in this blog post](http://juristr.com/blog/2016/04/angular2-change-detection/). (i.e. create a new `filterArgs` object every time an input field gets updated)

Comment: I also think that this is the better option for your situation.